# WooCommerce Product Spacing

Tags: css, wordpress

I simply want to decrease the product spacing in my storefront. I am using a child theme and tried adding css from here and there to the child theme style.css but nothing had an effect.

[image: (Screenshot: Spacing Problem)]

Can someone please help me adjust this product spacing. Despite resizing the thumbnails, the padding is too wide.

Please Help !

Comment: you can at least show us the site, or the code of the page .. we are not mind reader

Comment: LOL. The link is http://mubyinternational.com/PANDA/web/ 
I tried this in the CSS but none of the parameters had any effect:

.archive #wrapper #content ul.products li a.button {display:none; }
ul.products li.product {clear:none; width:50%; margin:0; padding:0;}
.woocommerce-page #main {max-width: 1100px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code :

```
.storefront-full-width-content .site-main .columns-3 ul.products li.product {
    width: 20%!important;
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly ! Thanks !